Unable to access google applications on SSO using SAML. Google workspace is Service provider and Okta is IDP
I’m trying to connect to Google Workspace via Okta IDP using SAML 2.0 for our company (to all users). I’ve tried using 1-click configuration to configure Google Workspace directly and added missing URLs.
Background:
Using Testing tool - Connection is shown Allowed.
Enabled Provisioning and Authenticated API integrations
Imported users from the company domain to the app and assigned them to the app.
On Google Admin-console >> Security >> Authentication >> SSO using third-party IDP >> Manage SSO profiles and set up the new Okta-generated SSO profile for Google workspace as the SSO profile for the entire organization.
Checked Okta system logs - All events success
Checked OAuth event logs on Google - All success
Tried logging in to Google Applications like Gmail, Calendar, GDrive etc that I added to the Okta dashboard while connecting. After Successful authentication >> All I see is a message from Google on screen saying “Couldn’t sign you in. Contact your admin.”
I’m unsure what is causing the issue and completely unaware of how to resolve this.
I’ll be more than happy to provide more information if needed.
Any help is appreciated :slight_smile:
I tried enabling SSO on Google admin console for the entire org unit and tried logging in to my gmail account via Okta.
After successful authentication - seeing "Couldn't sign you in. Contact your admin" message from Google. No failure message is seen on Okta system logs.
